# Daily in terms of annual

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, numbers

A frequency of events can be expressed using **annual** (once per year).
Also prefixes can be applied to increase the frequency during the year:
**bi**annual (twice per year), **tri**annual (thrice per year), etc.

That got me think that one could express daily as "365 times per year", which I determined to be something like **tricentasexagintaquintannual**.

Now Google does not find that word or anything similar, so it is probably never used. I would just like to know whether this is the correct way to build such a word, as I am not a linguistics expert.

Comment: It won't work, sadly, in a leap year, though.

Comment: I can live with one day of vacation. :)

Comment: Hello, Felix. Perhaps the first rule of English any of us should take on board is 'Avoid anything sounding or looking barbarous, even at the expense of breaking other rules or being left with awkward gaps in the capabilities of the language' (after Orwell). So something may be grammatically correct, semantically correct, morphologically 'correct' ... but unacceptable (other than when used skilfully in comedies, say). Many believe that the definition of 'word' sensibly includes a 'used and understood by a reasonable user-base (at some time)'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess, I was so preoccupied with whether I could, that I didn't stop to think whether I should.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But unfortunately, *pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis* is for real.

Comment: I suppose if you're a manufacturer of printers' ink you might prefer ***tricentasexagintaquintannual***, but most of us will stick with ***daily***.

Comment: Perhaps [*triacosihexacontapentannual*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360-gon).

Comment: But why? When you speak of events that happen frequently, why would you use such a long 'base measure'? 'Biannual' makes sense to use, since twice a year is a pretty long time too. You wouldn't say 'thirty-sixth-of-a-yard' or 'eighty-six-thousand-and-four-hundredths-of-an-hour', because there's no need to.

Answer (score 1):

Perennial might fit the bill.

perennial (adj.)

> 1640s, "evergreen," formed in English from Latin perennis "lasting
>   through the year (or years)," from per "through" (from PIE root *per-
>   (1) "forward," hence "through") + annus "year" (see annual (adj.)).
>   Botanical sense of "Remaining alive through a number of years" is
>   attested from 1670s; figurative meaning of "enduring, permanent" is
>   from 1750. Related: Perennially. For vowel change, see biennial. The
>   noun meaning "a perennial plant" is from 1763.

https://www.etymonline.com/word/perennial